# List Fragment not Clickable

Tags: android, fragment, android-listfragment

I have a class extending a list fragment, and for some reason, the fragment is not receiving the list item clicks. I have narrowed down the problem to the row items, but I still can't see what the problem is. Here is my XML. Any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:focusable="true">   
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/image_button"
    android:layout_width="120px"
    android:layout_height="120px"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
```

Here is how I inflate this layout in my custom adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
    View view = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    T t = list.get(position);
    TextView tv1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_view1);
    tv1.setText(t.getName());
    ImageButton image= (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.image_button);
    image.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("blue"));
    return view;
  }
```

Comment: I think this is your row layout, first try commenting the image button, then run and check

Comment: add this to ImageButton `android:focusable="false"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="false"`

Comment: @viv Thank you. Sadly, that is not it. Just tried it.

Comment: paste your java code, please

Comment: @Raghunandan Thank you for your time. Doing that still doesn't help.

Comment: @viv This is essentially it, changing to the simple list item, the built one, fixes it.

Comment: @RaymondMachira need more info your xml looks fine

Comment: simple list item is just a normal textview in row, if you comment out button, remove foccusable=true, then its near about the same thing

Comment: @RaymondMachira can you post your java code also

Comment: I have added the code for how I inflate the view.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason for android:focusable="true" in your parent layout, unless you're trying to achieve what seems to be your problem : switch focus from the list to the list item. Remove that element from your layout and it will work fine.

**Revised version :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:focusable="true">   
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/image_button"
        android:layout_width="120px"
        android:layout_height="120px"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
```